# Is it possible to use array_agg result in unnest? | PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am tring to insert data to `PostgreSQL` table from array. My next sql query raise error. Why I can't use `ARRAY_AGG` in `UNNEST`?

```
INSERT INTO surveys_questions_relationship(survey_id, question_id)
SELECT '9bef1274-f1ee-4879-a60e-16e94e88df38' ID, x
FROM UNNEST(
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG (QUESTION_ID)
    FROM factors_questions_relationship 
    WHERE FACTOR_ID = 10
) x
```

Subquery inside `UNNEST` return list of ids `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`. How correctly create array to `UNNEST`?

Comment: Why would you aggregate the values just to unnest them immediately after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the reason for aggregation or unnesting in your statement.

You can simply write:

```
INSERT INTO surveys_questions_relationship(survey_id, question_id)
SELECT '9bef1274-f1ee-4879-a60e-16e94e88df38', QUESTION_ID
FROM factors_questions_relationship 
WHERE FACTOR_ID = 10;
```